# get text separated by <wbr> from anchor tag in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

How do I get all the text inside the tag, i.e.: `"Digital Business Designer (m/w/d)"` from a tag like this

```
<a class="title">Digital Business Designer (m/<wbr>w/<wbr>d)</a>
```

I have tried the code below but it returns `"Digital Business Designer (m/"` only.

```
    async def parse(self, response):
        programs = response.css('#programslist')
        for program in programs.css('.title'):
            title = program.css('::text').get()
            title = re.sub(r'<wbr>', '', title)
            yield {'title': title}
```

Comment: Did you still have further questions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xpath `//text()` directive to get the inner text for an element and all it's children, in a list, when combined with `getall()`.  Then you can just use `''.join()`  to combine the text back into a single string.

For example:

```
from scrapy.http.response.text  import TextResponse

def parse(response):
    lst = response.xpath("//a[@class='title']//text()").getall()
    text = "".join(lst)
    print(text)

doc = """
<html>
    <body>
        <a class="title">Digital Business Designer (m/<wbr>w/<wbr>d)</a>
    </body>
</html>
""".encode("utf8")

response = TextResponse("url", body=doc)
parse(response)
```

OUTPUT

```
Digital Business Designer (m/w/d)
```